# How to get an object which consist of all properties satisfies the specified regex

Tags: javascript, regex, object

Let I have a JavaScript object like the following: `{a: 'a', b: 'b' , c: 'c'}`. I want ot return an object which consist of the properties satisfies, for instance `a\b`regexp. Is it possible to do in JavaScript?

Comment: What exactly `a\b` should match and return?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, should it be a **AND** b, or a **OR** b?

Comment: Should that not be `a|b` ?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv (facepalm) `\b` is a wordboundary. So you meant `a|b`. Please at least show your attempts and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have a function for this, however it is possible if you loop over the keys yourself, using `for (key in array) {}`. Then you can apply the regex to each key seperately and retrieve the corresponding value if it matches.